# Invalid sync source in mongodb config server

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 config servers 1 primary and 2 secondaries i have received Waring alerts
in secondary servers as

> Log File Monitoring : key = error, File = /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
>   (mgdb09:log[/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log,@mongodb_error,UTF-8]):
>   2018-05-05T05:42:08.913+0900 W REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] Fetcher
>   stopped querying remote oplog with error: InvalidSyncSource: sync
>   source mgdb08:27019 (last visible optime: { ts: Timestamp
>   1525466619000|1, t: 24 }; config version: 1; sync source index: -1;
>   primary index: 1) is no longer valid
>
> Log File Monitoring : key = error, File = /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
>   (mgdb07:log[/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log,@mongodb_error,UTF-8]):
>   2018-05-05T05:37:19.219+0900 W REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] Fetcher
>   stopped querying remote oplog with error: InvalidSyncSource: sync
>   source mgdb08:27019 (last visible optime: { ts: Timestamp
>   1525466619000|1, t: 24 }; config version: 1; sync source index: -1;
>   primary index: 2) is no longer valid
>
> . Log File Monitoring : key = error, File =
>   /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
>   (mgdb09:log[/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log,@mongodb_error,UTF-8]):
>   2018-05-05T05:42:13.911+0900 I REPL     [SyncSourceFeedback]
>   SyncSourceFeedback error sending update to mgdb08:27019:
>   InvalidSyncSource: Sync source was cleared. Was mgdb08:27019

and later on one of the secondary became primary

what cause this kind of issue what action do i need

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you update MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 1):

As I am able to see in your error log file such as error `Fetcher stopped querying remote oplog with error: InvalidSyncSource: sync source`

As per `MongoDB jira` documentation [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26494) It seems that the common cause for the remote replSetUpdatePosition failing with those error codes NodeNotFound,NotMasterOrSecondary and InvalidReplicaSetConfig would be a change in config. Config changes currently will cause the oplog fetcher to fail because it will detect a change in the config version contained in the oplog query metadata. Subsequently, after exiting the oplog fetcher, we will go back to the sync source resolver which has its own blacklisting logic.

For your further ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-secondary-sync-target/)

Comment: mongodb version is 3.3

Comment: so will this cause any issue

Comment: @askh,What is your MongoDB version(x,y,z)? Which you have your config server configuration?

Comment: Mongodb version is 3.4.3

Comment: So your config server have higher version than rest of cluster?

Comment: no my config server has same version 3.4.3 for all shard and config server